# 0.1" Snap fit header

Tags: connector

Looking for ideas. We have a product that has a 4 hole, 0.1" pitch standard through hole pads (normally for a 0.1" pin strip) however, we need to make a cable up for it, that, in most cases wont use it hence the pin strip is non fit. My question is does anyone know of a "male" 0.1" pitch, 4 way 'plug' that could snap into those holes. Like a debug fitment, like pogo pins but self retaining, and cheap. Essentially a connector that has a standard 4x0.1" pin strip throughhole footprint as its mating connection.

Comment: I know you can get a 'row of springs' connector for going between boards in the lowest cost way, but they would need an additional hole or two to hold them mechanically. You might get your question closed, as suggesting any specific product is off topic.

Comment: I've seen press-fit (no-solder) headers, but typically these are many more pins than 4.

Comment: Would it be possible to place the holes so that is really easy to solder on the pin headers if needed, or is it too late now?

Comment: PCBs are a;ready made :(

Comment: [like this](https://www.samtec.com/connectors/micro-pitch-board-to-board/compression/0100)

Answer (score 1):

Staggering the holes in the footprint slightly, as shown in this [Sparkfun tutorial](https://www.sparkfun.com/tutorials/114), allows an ordinary header with 0.025" square pins to make reasonably reliable contact without solder.

If the PCB is already made, it may be possible to bend the pins of a header slightly, staggering them in a complementary way in order to get the same overall effect.

Comment: What amount of staggering would be necessary to get this to work?  I sort of want to do this but don't want to have to pay NRE multiple times while I play with the spacing.  My first guess would be something like a 10 mil offset?

Comment: Like I said, there are existing examples to draw from. But if you want to work it out from scratch yourself, you spend the NRE once to create a test board that has multiple amounts of stagger, and pick the one that works best for your header.